# JavaFx kill Task

Tags: java, sockets, javafx

I am working on a JavaFX project in which I am fetching data from a device connected to the network using socket (java.net.Socket) API. I am facing two main problems. The first problem is that I am unable to terminate the task. The Code inside the if a block of FetchTask is never executed.

```
     if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){

        System.out.println("i am breaking out");
        break;

    }
```

The second problem is that I am unable to close the socket. If I close the BufferReadeader first and then close the socket the UI freezes, However if I choose to close the socket first and then close the bufferReader then I get the following exception.

```
java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
    at connector.FetchTask.call(FetchTask.java:52)
    at connector.FetchTask.call(FetchTask.java:14)
    at javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable.call(Task.java:1423)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

This is my Complete Controller Code ->

```
public class ControllerDbase implements Initializable{

    @FXML
    private TableView dataTable;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn dataTable_Column;

    @FXML
    private ToggleButton connectToggle;

    private Socket socket = null;
    private BufferedReader inputBuffer = null;


    FetchTask fetchTask;

    private static ObservableList<SqlData> data;

    Connection con ;
    public static volatile boolean closesignal = false;

    public void connectAction(ActionEvent actionEvent) {


        if (connectToggle.isSelected()){


            try {
                //socket = new Socket("192.168.1.36",80);
                System.out.println("Connecting to : " + Selected_IP.ip_Hold);
                socket = new Socket(Selected_IP.ip_Hold,80);
                inputBuffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

                //thread.start();
                fetchTask = new FetchTask(con,inputBuffer);

                new Thread( fetchTask).start();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }else {

            try {

                fetchTask.cancel();
                socket.close();
                inputBuffer.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    }

    public void ephantAction(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException {

        try {
            socket.getOutputStream().write('d');
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("progressbar.fxml"));
        Parent root1 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        stage.setTitle("ABC");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root1));
        stage.show();

    }

    public void printAction(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

        //System.out.println("hello i am printing");

        try {
            printResult(con);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        TableColumn firstNameCol = new TableColumn("Dolphin");
        firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<SqlData,String>("firstName"));



        data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                //new connector.SqlData("dummy value")
        );


        dataTable.setItems(data);
        dataTable.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol);

        try {
            con = getConnection();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        Connection con = null;

        String url = "jdbc:sqlite:wolf.db";
        // create a connection to the database
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

        System.out.println("Connection to SQLite has been established.");
        return con;
    }

    private static void printResult(Connection con) throws SQLException {
        //reading records

        Statement st = con.createStatement();;

        System.out.println("Reading records:");
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from foobar");

        while(rs.next()){

            System.out.println(rs.getString("indata"));

            data.add(new SqlData(rs.getString("indata")));

        }

        st.close();
        rs.close();

    }

    private static void storeInt(Connection con, int storedata) throws SQLException {

        String sql = "insert into foobar(indata) values (?)";
        PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        pstmt.setInt(1, storedata);
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
    }

}
```

This is is FetchTask code ->

```
public class FetchTask extends Task<Void> {

    public  boolean exitFlag = false;

    private BufferedReader inputBuffer = null;

    private Connection connection;

    FetchTask(Connection connect, BufferedReader inputBuffer){

        this.connection =  connect;
        this.inputBuffer = inputBuffer;
    }

    private void storeInt(Connection con, int storedata) throws SQLException {

        String sql = "insert into foobar(indata) values (?)";
        PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        pstmt.setInt(1, storedata);
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
    }


    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {

        while (!isCancelled()){

            if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){

                System.out.println("i am breaking out");
                break;

            }

            String inMsg = null;
            try {

                inMsg = inputBuffer.readLine();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (!inMsg.isEmpty()) {

                System.out.println(inMsg);

                try {

                    storeInt(connection, Integer.parseInt(inMsg));

                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        }

        System.out.println("exiting thread");

        return null;
    }
}
```

So I want to know how can I terminate both Fetch data Task and Socket when the toggle button is deselected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you cannot `interrupt()` a blocking read on a `Socket`.

The standard way of interrupting a blocking read is indeed to close the socket.

Hence, you can implement a cancel action like

```
@Override
protected void cancelled() {
  try {
    socket.close();
  } catch( IOException e ) {
    // Never mind.
  }
}
```

and in your `protected Void call()` you can catch and ignore any (IO-)Exception *if* the task is already cancelled.

```
try {
  ...
} catch ( IOException e ) {
  if ( this.isCancelled() ) {
    // May ignore the exception. We're terminating anyway.
  } else {
    throw e; // Not cancelled -> Need to propagate the exception.
  }
}
```

Comment: is it okay to close the socket before closing BufferedReader ?

Comment: Yes, that's perfectly ok.